# Why js regex freezes a browser on newlines?

Tags: javascript, regex

When I just select one line it works fine, but if I select a few lines it starts to process data and linger forever loading processor. I think the regex doesn't see a sybmols of new line. So how I can fix it?

```js
 function Selection () {
               
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            var container = document.createElement("div");
            for (var i = 0, len = sel.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
                container.appendChild(sel.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());
            }
            html = container.innerHTML;
        }
    } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined") {
        if (document.selection.type == "Text") {
            html = document.selection.createRange().htmlText;
        }
    }
    
     html = html.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
                       
    var patt1 = /id=\"load+(.*)+<\/a>/g;
    var result = html.match(patt1);
    alert(result);     

        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>

<div class="text" onmouseup="Selection()">
You &nbsp;
<br><a class="good" data-id="1114" href="#load" id="load1114">are very </a> important for us.
<br>So we're offering you 
<br><a class="good" data-id="1114" href="#load" id="load1114"> win-win</a> option.
<br>You will get 2 refrigerators if you buy one

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you mean to match anything from `id="load` till the last `</a>`? Then you need to replace `(.*)+` with `[\s\S]*`. If up to the first `</a>` replace `(.*)+` with `[\s\S]*?`. Try `/id="load([\s\S]*?)<\/a>/g`

Comment: Which line of code does it get up to before freezing? What is `.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"")` doing that `.replace(/\n|\r/gm,"")` wouldn't do?

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew, thank you! I tried to use [\s\S]* but my code looked 
 /id=\"load+[\s\S]*+<\/a>/g; so it didn't work.

Comment: The `html = html.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"")` should be removed, I believe.

Comment: # nnnnnn, no one of these regexes doesn't help anyway, the problem was in here var patt1 = /id=\"load+(.*)+<\/a>/g;

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew , Of course, I've removed it. ;)